# Is there a simple way to create a hierarchical data structure in Java that can be modified at runtime and saved to a file? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, data-structures, android-studio

I'm trying to find a simple way in Java/Android Studio to create a runtime-modifiable data structure that I can save/load from file that will be parsed to create a hierarchy of buttons (buttons that lead to child buttons).  In javascript I could do something like this:

```
var categories = new Object(
    "Entertainment": new Object(
        "Movie": null),
    "Exercise": new Object(
        "Upper Body": null,
        "Lower Body": new Object(
            "Squats": null
        ),
        "Dance": null)
);
```

and then I could modify this object at runtime, use the data-structure to update and create a hierarchy of buttons, then serialize it to JSON and save it to a file to reload any edits the user made.

To accomplish this I tried to create a tree/node data structure but I'm getting errors that I don't understand:

```
public static class Branch extends HashMap{
        public HashMap<String, HashMap> Branch(String str, HashMap node){
            HashMap<String, HashMap> hmap = new HashMap<>();
            hmap.put(str, node);
            return hmap;
        }
    }

    public static class ButtonHierarchy {
        private ArrayList<HashMap> categories;

        public ButtonHierarchy(){
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap>> categories = new ArrayList<>();

            categories.add(new Branch("entertainment", new HashMap()));
            categories.add(new Branch("exercise", null));

        }

        public Iterator<Map.Entry> iterator() {
            return categories.iterator();
        }
    }
```

Android Studio flags the `categories.add` calls because `Branch() in Branch cannot be applied to:
(java.lang.String, java.util.HashMap)`
I don't understand because I defined the `Branch` constructor to accept those types.

Maybe I'm going about this in a way that doesn't lend itself to Java?  Is there already a standard Java class/lib that simplifies making this kind of mechanism?  I'm open to a totally different approach if it will simplify things!!  I'm not concerned about speed/memory because the button hierarchy will not be very big.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"categories" is a list of HashMaps, but you try to add a Branch to it. Also, your custom Branch constructor is not a constructor but a method.

Your simplest option to do the same thing you did in Javascript is probably to use the org.json API: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

If you prefer to create strongly-typed and well-defined POJOs, you can too. A library like Gson allows to persist and restore any Java data structure easily: https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're having is that the `Branch` method in your code isn't a constructor. Constructors don't return anything but yours does:

```
// This declares a method that returns a HashMap so it isn't a constructor for Branch()
public HashMap<String, HashMap> Branch(String str, HashMap node)
```

If all you want to do is serialize a `HashMap<String, HashMap>` I'd suggest you look at tools that are designed to make this really easy like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), or [ProtocolBuffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).